# Counting number of lines with occurrence of specific word

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to count number of lines in a text file that contain a specific word "uniqueId".

I used the following code but always get 0 where I can count about 1000+ occurrences.

```
var total = 0;
char[] delimiters = new[] { '\r', '\n' };

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var counts = sr
            .ReadLine()
            .Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .GroupBy(s => s)
            .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
        var wc = counts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Word == "uniqueId");
        total += (wc == null) ? 0 : wc.Count;
    }
}
```

Sample text file entry:

```
2023-07-31 07:26:35.211|Message sent (value: '{"uniqueId":1527258,"Node":"13","lclDtm":"2023-07-31T07:18:38.803","utcDtm":"2023-07-31T11:18:38.803","errorCode":"E45"}'). Delivery status: Persisted; Partition: 1; Offset: 161454; Created (UTC): 7/31/2023 11:26:34 AM

2023-07-31 07:26:35.648|Message sent (value: '{"uniqueId":1527291,"Node":"13","lclDtm":"2023-07-31T07:19:15.444","utcDtm":"2023-07-31T11:19:15.444","errorCode":"E45"}'). Delivery status: Persisted; Partition: 1; Offset: 161455; Created (UTC): 7/31/2023 11:26:35 AM
```

Comment: May be the problem is a line doesn't contain lines. Are you sure `delimiters` is correct?

Comment: Check your group keys. They do not contain what you think they do.

Comment: @derloopkat I am trying to split by newline; is it not correct?

Comment: Updated with sample line containing the search work.

Comment: *search word not search work

Comment: @dr.null Please change your comment to answer and I will mark it as such. Thank you, worked just fine. My post seems to have read all the line but continued to process same line over and over and never finding "uniqueId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count on `RegEx` for problems like this. A one liner example:

```cs
int count = File.ReadLines(fi.FullName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "uniqueId"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```cs
void countUniqueId()
{
    string inFile = @"D:\junk\input.txt";
    int count = 0;
    foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(inFile))
    {
        if (line.IndexOf("uniqueId") > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

If you need it to be case-insensitive, you can use `line.ToUpper().IndexOf("UNIQUEID")`